# What is required to transit through Istanbul when I need to collect my luggage?

Tags: air-travel, transit, turkey, istanbul

I am a Nigerian citizen and I traveled to Sofia through Istanbul for a business trip (Turkish Airlines). I have another booking from Istanbul to London.

How can I claim my luggage to check in for my flight to London? What will be required of me by Turkish authorities?

<sup>I will return from London back to istanbul on British Airways to continue my flight back to Nigeria with Turkish Airlines.</sup>

Comment: So you're currently in Sofia, and your next booking is from Istanbul to London? How are you going to get to Istanbul?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Presumably by air, since OP talks about "collecting luggage" in Istanbul. I-jay: Please provide some details regarding your flight from Sofia to Istanbul, and the next one to London. Did you book them separately?

Answer (score 1):

Since you talk about "collecting luggage", I'm assuming you have separate bookings for Sofia to Istanbul and Istanbul to London. (If you had a single booking, you wouldn't need to collect luggage, it would be automatically forwarded in Istanbul and you could stay in the transit lounge.)

[According to Turkish authorities:](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/frequently-asked-questions.en.mfa)

> If you will not leave the transit lounge at the airport you are not
>   required to have transit visa. Otherwise, you have to make visa
>   application to the nearest Turkish Representation.

It sounds like you *will* have to leave the transit lounge in order to collect your luggage and check in to the new flight.

Nigerian citizens [do need](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=NG&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=TR&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C) visas for Turkey. The source doesn't mention any exceptions for UK visa holders.

I have not found any information on where transit visas can be applied for for Turkey. All sites I have seen offer information only on [tourist, business and e-visas.](https://turkey.travisa.com/Common/TVSVisaInstructions.aspx?citizenshipid=NG&countryid=tr&residenceid=aus&partnerid=ta&glid=aus)

The most convenient visa to get would perhaps be an e-visa.

There is a [website to apply for e-visas for Turkey](https://www.evisa.gov.tr/en/apply/).